# How to configure Advantage Database NET provider to use LINQ with free dbf tables?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, dbf, advantage-database-server

I try Advantage Database server as data provider for MVC application. Data source is free Visual FoxPro's tables. I define DbContext, data provider and simple LINQ as shown below

**provider**: 
invariantName="Advantage.Data.Provider" type="Advantage.Data.Provider.AdsProviderServices, EntityFramework.Advantage.v12, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"

**connectionStrings**: tested both of them
name="Context1_ads" connectionString="Data Source=D:\PathToData\; ServerType=LOCAL; TableType=CDX;" providerName="Advantage.Data.Provider"

name="Context2_ads" connectionString="Data Source=\\AdsSrv:6262\Data; TableType=CDX;" providerName="Advantage.Data.Provider"

```
[Table("STATE", Schema = "::this")] // is this needed?
public class State
{
    public string Guid { get; set; }
    public string Pseudonim { get; set; }
    public string Statename { get; set; }
    //...
}
//Mapping
public class StateMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<State>
{
public StateMap()
{
    this.ToTable("State");
    this.HasKey(t => t.Guid);
    //...
}
}
// Query
ctx.States.Where(t => t.Pseudonim=="Nim").SingleOrDefault();
```

And get:
Error 7200:  AQE Error:  State = HY000;   NativeError = 5041;  [SAP][Advantage SQL Engine][ASA] Error 5041:  The requested object was not found.  dbo - link object is not supported on free connection. Table name: State  AdsCommand query execution failed.
Genetated query:

```
SELECT 
"Limit1"."Guid" AS "Guid"
FROM ( SELECT TOP 2 
    "Extent1"."Guid" AS "Guid"
    FROM "dbo"."State" "Extent1"
    WHERE (("Extent1"."Pseudonim" = :p__linq__0) OR (("Extent1"."Pseudonim" IS NULL) AND (:p__linq__0 IS NULL)))
)  "Limit1"
```

Is possible use LINQ to dbf with Advantage provider?

Comment: ADS doesn't support schemas, so you have to somehow get link to not omit a schema. Have you tried setting Schema to "" (empty string)?

Comment: Yes, I tried empty schema [Schema=""], but System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations threw error: "The argument 'value' can not be empty, be NULL or contains only spaces."

Comment: Also, I tried without annotation [Table("STATE", Schema = "::this")] - ADS provider trew the same error 5041.

Comment: Oh! Soved this problem by adding default schema for DbContext: modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **default** schema for DbContext:

```
modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("");
```